# Gradle custom plugin dependencies

Tags: gradle

If a have a custom plugin which handles the building and deploying of a specific component, where do I list the dependencies (other components in my system) which are required for the build?

Comment: This question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies for your Gradle plugins should be listed in the `buildscript` portion of the build.gradle file. See [this chapter of the User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:applying_plugins_buildscript), which also has an example:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:0.4.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.jfrog.bintray"
```

If your custom plugin depends on jar files on your local machine, I gather that you need to add those files as a "flatDir" repository in the `repositories` entry, [as described here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:flat_dir_resolver):

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib1', 'lib2'
    }
}
```